# How do i set variable after repeat until loop?

Tags: lua, computercraft

i've got a query about my code. I currently cant test it so i thought i'd ask. (for context i'm very new to lua) Hopefully i'm not asking a duplicate question, or anything similar.

here's my code currently

```
write("Column: ")
local column = tonumber( read() )
write("Row: ")
local row = tonumber( read() )
local x = 0
local y = 0

function digforward(str)
    repeat
        turtle.dig()
        turtle.forward()
        x = x+1
    until x == column
```

So after the repeat until loop ends, what would i do to set the variable x back to 0? I'm aware that x = 0 would normally do it, but i want to make it so when you run the function it goes till x = column and then set x to 0.

Additionally just so you know this is code for a computer in a game. (from the computercraft mod for minecraft)

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you mean by 'I'm aware that x = 0 would normally do it ...'. Why don't you do that? Just place that after the repeat-loop and you're fine?

Comment: @pschulz because i assume when i call the function it won't run that aswell.

Comment: You do `x = 0`.....

Comment: Have you learned that the computer does things in the order you write them, not all at once? It won't do `x=0` until it gets to the `x=0` part.

Comment: @user253751 yes i've learned that, but i'm unsure of if it would work to put x = 0 after that loop. Are you guys saying to put it in the function after the loop, or outside?

Comment: You put it at the part of the program when you want it to happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, it'd be better to just use a numeric for-loop:

```lua
for x = 1, column do
   turtle.dig()
   turtle.forward()
end
```

And as a small extra:

```lua
for x = 1, column do
   while not turtle.forward() do
      turtle.dig()
   end
end
```

This makes sure to re-try until the turtle actually manages to move, like when a sand block falls down immediately after digging. You can also throw in an attack for good measure for cases when an enemy is blocking the movement.

Comment: Thanks! I had considered something similar, but i wasn't sure what type of loop to do